# CaliburnMicro cannot find view for view model in different assembly

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Recently I have begun to reorganize one of my projects into smaller assemblies. In one step I moved my views and view models into separate assemblies while keeping the Views and VMs that belong together in a common assembly. Thus my project structure looks like this:

- Main
- Core
- Modules <- Folder

  - CharacterPresenter
  - LocationPresenter

Namespaces are like this:

- RpgTools

  - Main

    - ViewModels
    - Views
  - LocationPresenter

    - ViewModels
    - Views
  - Other projects follow the same system.

"Main" contains bootstrapper and d minimalistic vm and view to select a module. Each presenter contains ALL the views and view models needed for that presenter. "Core" contains assets used by every project in the folder (e.g. metadata definitions, export interfaces, etc.)

Now after the move Caliburn.Micro cannot find the views for the view model, no matter how simple it is. Here is an example of a view model and view:

```
namespace RpgTools.LocationPresenter.ViewModels
{
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
    using RpgTools.Core.Contracts;

    [RpgModuleMetadata(Name = "Module C")]
    [Export(typeof(IRpgModuleContract))]
    public class ModuleCViewModel :IRpgModuleContract
    {
    }
}
```

---

```
<UserControl x:Class="RpgTools.LocationPresenter.Views.ModuleCView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="ModuleC" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Every time I load the module I get the following error:

> Cannot find view for RpgTools.LocationPresenter.ViewModels.ModuleCViewModel.

If I move the model back to "Main" it works just fine. Since it could be something with the bootstrapper here is the complete code of it:

```
namespace RpgTools.Main
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives;
    using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Windows;

    using Caliburn.Micro;

    using RpgTools.Core.Contracts;

    /// <summary>The MEF bootstrapper.</summary>
    [SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1650:ElementDocumentationMustBeSpelledCorrectly", Justification = "Reviewed. Suppression is OK here.")]
    public class MefBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        /// <summary>The composition container.</summary>
        private CompositionContainer compositionContainer;

        /// <summary>Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="MefBootstrapper"/> class.</summary>
        public MefBootstrapper()
        {
            // this.CheckModuleDirectory();

            this.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>Override to configure the framework and setup your IoC container.</summary>
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            // Get the modules from the module directory
            // ToDo: Implement dynamic loading from modules directory.
            DirectoryCatalog dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@".");

            // Create a combinable catalog
            // ReSharper disable once RedundantEnumerableCastCall
            AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog(AssemblySource.Instance.Select(s => new AssemblyCatalog(s)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>());
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(dirCatalog);

            // Create a new composition container.
            // ReSharper disable once RedundantEnumerableCastCall
            this.compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer();

            // Create a new composition container.
            this.compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

            CompositionBatch compositionBatch = new CompositionBatch();

            // Add window manager to composition batch.
            compositionBatch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new ToolsWindowManager());

            // Add EventAggregator to composition batch.
            compositionBatch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());

            // Add the container itself.
            compositionBatch.AddExportedValue(this.compositionContainer);

            // Compose the container.
            this.compositionContainer.Compose(compositionBatch);
        }

        /// <summary>Override this to provide an IoC specific implementation.</summary>
        /// <param name="service">The service to locate.</param>
        /// <param name="key">The key to locate.</param>
        /// <returns>The located service.</returns>
        protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
        {
            // Check if the contract is null or an empty string, if so return the contract name from the service itself.
            string contractName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(service) : key;

            // Get a collection of exported values with the goven contract name. 
            IList<object> exports = this.compositionContainer.GetExportedValues<object>(contractName).ToList();

            if (exports.Any())
            {
                return exports.First();
            }

            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contractName));
        }

        /// <summary>Override this to provide an IoC specific implementation</summary>
        /// <param name="serviceType">The service to locate.</param> 
        /// <returns>The located services.</returns>
        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
        {
            return this.compositionContainer.GetExportedValues<object>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType));
        }

        /// <summary>Override this to provide an IoC specific implementation.</summary>
        /// <param name="instance"> The instance to perform injection on.</param>
        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            this.compositionContainer.SatisfyImportsOnce(instance);
        }

        /// <summary>Override this to add custom behaviour to execute after the application starts.</summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The args.</param>
        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
        }

        /// <summary>Checks if the modules directory exists and if not create it.</summary>
        private void CheckModuleDirectory()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(@".\Modules"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@".\Modules");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I might add taht the module discovery works fine. My ShellView model  displays every module in every project I added fine, just the loading of the views does not work if the view is located in a different assembly than "Main"

---

I fixed the original Problem by overriding the `SelectAssemblies()` method with the following code:

```
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
{
    var assemblies = Directory.GetFiles(ModuleDirectory, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(Assembly.LoadFrom).ToList();
    assemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    return assemblies;
}
```

However now all my modules are getting loaded twice! This is the only change in the code I made. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to override `SelectAssemblies` in the `Bootstrapper` to include the assembly containing your Views.  By default Caliburn Micro will only include the assembly the `Bootstrapper` is defined in.

From the [documentation](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/bootstrapper):

> So, what is AssemblySource.Instance? This is the place that Caliburn.Micro looks for Views. You can add assemblies to this at any time during your application to make them available to the framework, but there is also a special place to do it in the Bootstrapper. Simply override SelectAssemblies like this:

```
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
{
    return new[] {
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    };
}
```

> All you have to do is return a list of searchable assemblies. By default, the base class returns the assembly that your Application exists in. So, if all your views are in the same assembly as your application, you don’t even need to worry about this. If you have multiple referenced assemblies that contain views, this is an extension point you need to remember.

Comment: Even if the assembly that contains the ViewModels also contains the Views?

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot yes. If I remember correctly you give the framework a view model and its default locator uses this to find a view. It does this via namespace and searches the registered assemblies.

Comment: Would this process work with a directory catalog? Or do I have to load all the assemblies via `Assembly.Load()`?

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot my MEF is a bit rusty - but unless you want to change the default locator function, you need a list of assemblies here. I'd suggest starting simple (e.g. include typeof(ModuleCViewModel).Assembly), confirm it works, then work out how you solve with MEF or dynamically otherwise.

Comment: I updated my original Question with additional Information. I got it working but now have another problem.

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot you have a `DirectoryCatalog` that loads all assemblies in the directory, and you also create an `AssemblyCatalog` for each assembliy in `AssemblySource.Instance` - `AssemblySource.Instance` will return all assemblies loaded by `SelectAssemblies`, so they're all added twice.  Remove the `DirectoryCatalog`.

Comment: Did that and now it works like a charm. Any idea why the directory catalogue does not load only the viewmodels and not the views? Even though they are in the same assembly file?

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot as I mentioned above, the Calburn ViewLocator does some find/replace on the qualified name and comes up with some target names for the View.  It uses its `AssemblySource` to search those assemblies registered from `SelectAssemblies` - it doesn't matter what is loaded elsewhere. See the code for [LocateTypeForModelType](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro.Platform/ViewLocator.cs) if interested in the detail.

Comment: O.K. I can live with that. Thanks for the help.